# Are these models with Django Manytomanyfield correct?

Tags: python, django

I am modeling actors an movies with Django and its manytomanyfield.
An actor can play in many movies and a movie has a cast composed of many actors.

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Actor,null=True,blank=True)
```

For each model, I would like to use inline display of the other model in admin page.

Is this code correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you do this, then you break the symmetry between the relationships; adding a movie to an actor's set of movies would not then show that actor as being in the cast of that movie.

You need to use one many-to-many field only, and decide which side you want to be the "parent" in the admin page.